# How to show Checkmark on tableview?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

i would like to make a verification on/off button to show is the student verified. Once the switch is turn on in the "AddStudentViewController", a checkmark will show at the right hand side of the specific student's row in the table list in "StudentDataBaViewController". May i know how to do that?

**Additional Information:

1)StudentDataBaViewContoller (1st page of the app) is a TableViewController
2)AddStudentViewController (2nd page of the app) is a normal View Controller

Both are connected with a Push Segue named "StuSegue"

Below attached the code of my 2 view controller:

---

Code for "StudentDataBaViewController":

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using SQLite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace One
{
public partial class StudentDataBaViewController : UITableViewController
{
    private string pathToDatabase;
    private List<Student> students;

    public StudentDataBaViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        students = new List<Student>();
    }

    /*public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        if (segue.Identifier == "StuSegue")
        { // set in Storyboard
            var navctlr = segue.DestinationViewController as AddStudentViewController;
            if (navctlr != null)
            {
                var source = TableView.Source as StudentDataBaViewController;
                var rowPath = TableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow;
                var item = source.GetItem(rowPath.Row);
                navctlr.SetTask(this, item); // to be defined on the TaskDetailViewController
            }
        }
    } 
    */

    //connect to student_da.db database file and create a table named Student
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        //path of the database
        var documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        pathToDatabase = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, "student_db.db");

        //connect database and create table
        using (var connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(pathToDatabase))
        {
            connection.CreateTable<Student>();
        }
     }

    //used to relaod or update new elements entered on the list
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        students = new List<Student>();

        using (var connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(pathToDatabase))
        {
            var query = connection.Table<Student>();

            foreach (Student student in query)
            {
                students.Add(student);
                TableView.ReloadData();

            }
        }
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return students.Count;
    }

    //make elements to be display on the database list
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("student");
        var data = students[indexPath.Row];

        cell.TextLabel.Text = data.StudentName;
        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = data.StudentId;

        return cell;
    }

    public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        switch (editingStyle)
        {
            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete:
                // remove the item from the underlying data source
                students.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
                // delete the row from the table
                tableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);


                break;
            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None:
                Console.WriteLine("CommitEditingStyle:None called");
                break;
        }
    }

}

public class Student
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string StudentId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StudentName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StudentPassword
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool StudentAttendence
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Code for "AddStudentViewController":

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.IO;
using UIKit;

namespace One
{
public partial class AddStudentViewController : UIViewController
{
    private string pathToDatabase;


    //used to access same database to grab data for display
    protected AddStudentViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        var documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        pathToDatabase = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, "student_db.db");
    }

    // create a function for save button
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        saveStudent.Clicked += SaveButton_Clicked;
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    //create connection with database and make handler for save button and insert the element into database
    void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(pathToDatabase))
        {
            connection.Insert(new Student() { StudentName = AddStuNameTxt.Text, StudentId = AddStuIdTxt.Text, StudentPassword = AddStuPassTxt.Text, StudentAttendence =true  });
            new UIAlertView("Updated !", "Student successfully created", null, "OK", null).Show();
        }

        //navigate page back to database list
        NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you are hoping refushing the UI in "StudentDataBaViewController" after the switch is turn on in the "AddStudentViewController".
you can use delegate to send message between two controllers.

Comment: Hi Joe, may I know how to do that?

Comment: for more information you can access https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/delegates-protocols-and-events